# Add 2 lines in listbox.Items.Add

Tags: listboxitem

I created a listbox (with winform) which represents a list of services.
I want to add many items in this list and each item should contain two values (Service Id and Service Name)

The goal is to display in my application the names of the Services and be able to get the Id of the selected service.

My code

```
  foreach (Service s in service.GetServices())
            {
                listbox_service.Items.Add(s.Id + s.Name);
              
            }
```

My code display my two values in my listbox but they are not independent of each other.

I want this :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2cUFq.jpg)

And be able to get only the id

Can you help me?

Comment: Do you have to use a listbox?  I would use a ListView and set the first column size to 0 with ID being in the first column and name in the second.  Then you get the index of the selected item and get the first columns value.  if you need a list box look here at MS: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listbox.multicolumn?view=windowsdesktop-6.0

Comment: Effectively, I didn't think to use a ListView ! 
Thank you for your help ;)